# Base64 Image does not render in Gmail & Outlook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, outlook, base64, sendgrid, email-templates

We are using SendGrid to send email to all the platforms, i.e., Gmail, Outlook etc.

Also designed the email template using SendGrid dynamic template.

We've base64 image and we used it in the email template. But, the image is not rendered in the SendGrid email template.

Also, we've tested it by sending the mail to Gmail and Outlook, but, there too the base64 image is not rendered.

Since the image is not uploaded anywhere, the editor saves the image as a base64-encoded image.

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAFKCAIAAADKUQaBAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhepP1p32zb"/>
```

Could you please anyone suggest to me the solution to render Base64 Image in email template for all platforms Gmail, Outlook, SendGrid, etc.

Comment: This is not a base 64 string

Comment: @logeshpalani31 I just tested it. It decodes fine, and the png opens fine in mspaint. The user should try doing it with an image that is not a single transparent color.

Comment: @GoWiser, The issue is that it will not render in GMAIL or OUTLOOK...and that is confirmed. You should remove your answer.

Comment: @JeffLongo Can you please elaborate - because I can not make sense of your comment? I tested the image, and it is a transparent image, which may cause you to believe that it does not work in email. The image is encoded correctly, it is used correctly in html, it works as expected, but it is transparent. Which is what my answer points out. Please be specific when you reply :D

Comment: @jeff And with regards to the CID debate/compatibility see: https://mailtrap.io/blog/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/

Comment: @GoWiser, sendgrid literally tells you this is fruitless and it will likely not work.

https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Answer (score 1):

Outlook doesn't support base64 images. Instead you need to embed an image by attaching a file and then referencing it using the `cid:` attribute in the message body.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing works fine. The problem is that your image is a single color, and the color is transparent.

You can verify this if you create this html file and open it in your browser:

```html
<body style="background-color:green;">
Text before
<img style="border:1px solid black;" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAFKCAIAAADKUQaBAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhepP1p32zb"/>
Text after
</body>
```